# rxjs: subscribing to observable in map

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

My first observable returns an array of Persons. I want to update each person of that array with a list of clients from second observable. How do I do that? So far I have this:

```
const json: Person[] = [new Person('Alice'), new Person('Bob')];

const resultsObservable = new Observable<string[]>(subscriber => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.next(['Client1', 'Client2', 'Client3']);
    subscriber.complete();
  }, 1000);
});

of(json).pipe(
  switchMap( dataArray => {
    return from(dataArray);
  }),
  map((x: Person) => {
    resultsObservable.subscribe(r => {
      x.clients = r;
    });
    return x;
  }),
).subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

}

Person:

```
export class Person{
  name: string;
  clients?: string[];

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

But the problem is that return happens before the values are set, so at the end value of person.clients is undefined. How do I fix this? Or what is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found what I was looking for:

```
    const result = persons.pipe(
      mergeMap(p => resultsObservable.pipe(map(clients => {
        p.clients = clients;
        return p;
      }))),
    );
    result.subscribe(p => console.log(p));
```

Comment: This isn't super important but `clients => ({...p, clients})` is a shorter, more declarative way to write your mapping function. :)